# How to prevent creating container from a docker image?

Tags: docker, image

I'd like to build a docker image which will the base of my containers, but I'd like to prevent creating a container directly from it.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible workaround you may add

```
ENTRYPOINT false
```

to clearly state the you want anyone to run containers from it.
Of course, it doesn't prevent container creation, but...

Comment: I didn't think so... It is perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

Every image (except `scratch`, which is a special case) can be used to create a container, so no it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent creating a container from your images, but you can prevent the container from running anything. Simply don't include anything runnable in the container.

An example of a base image that does this is [`centurylink/ca-certs`](https://hub.docker.com/r/centurylink/ca-certs/) (which is horribly out of date; don't use it for its intended purpose). It is based on `scratch` and its only content is a CA certificate bundle file. It is not possible to run anything from this container as it contains no scripts or executables.